# Access in IFrame and SetAttribute value

Tags: c#, html, iframe, webbrowser-control, setattribute

Normally I can access html tags and I can set their values via the code something like;

```
HtmlElementCollection coll = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement curElement in coll)
{
  if (curElement.GetAttribute("name").ToString() == "login")
  {
    curElement.SetAttribute("Value", "123456789"); 
  }
}
```

But if html input area exist in a iframe tag, This code didnt work,

And I changed line:

```
var coll = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
```

to

```
var coll = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe")
```

But it still didnt work. Please Help. I cannot get over this problem since last week

Comment: What  "doesn't work" mean? Any error info?

Comment: No giving error, I meaned, It can't setattribute the input field . But I soled the problem with Adam Valpied 's answer

Comment: Then you should tick Adam's answer as accepted, this his how he gets the credits for his help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it should work if you change this line:

```
coll = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe")
```

to

```
coll = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
```

Here is a working example...

```
HtmlWindow iframe = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
HtmlElement input = iframe.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[0];

input.SetAttribute("value", "Test");
```

This assumes obviously that you only have at least one iframe element and at least one input element in the child document.